# place text inside UISwitch in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

After 2 days try, I'm posting this question here. I need to achieve this [image]

in swift 4. I've tried below:-

```
let switchOnOff = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 200, height: 0))

    switchOnOff.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchStateDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    switchOnOff.setOn(true, animated: false)
    self.view.addSubview(switchOnOff) 


 @objc func switchStateDidChange(sender:UISwitch){
    if (sender.isOn == true){
        sender.setOn(true, animated: false)
        //sender.onImage = UIImage(named: "edit.png")
    }
    else{

        sender.setOn(false, animated: false)
        //sender.offImage = UIImage(named: "offSwitch.png")


    }
}
```

sender.onImage , sender.offImage not working in this ios 10+ version.
Then I tried to use `sender.tag` , `sender.text`

These are also not working. Not getting any proper help in googling.
So please help me if You already solved this matter.

Thanks Guys.

Comment: I suggest you create a custom view for this switch.

Comment: From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25104771/7734643), it seems obvious that you have to create your own.

Comment: Check [this](https://factory.hr/blog/uiswitch-part-2) blog

Comment: @premkolindala thank You for the blog link. I'll try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With default `UISwitch` you can not achieve it because it doesn't provide this much customisation. But here is third party lib [LabelSwitch](https://github.com/Cookiezby/LabelSwitch) which provide same customise you needed and it will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Comment: be aware that this project is not maintained

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 12 comes with a new property title on UISwitch type but it is only available for checkbox styled switches on Mac (iOS Catalyst), not on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvg5z.png)
here I am using button 
go to button property inspector

set the "State config" have option 1) default 3) selected
1)select "Default"  and set image for default button image
2)select "selected" set the image for selected button image
here my button name is "LocaionOnOffSwiftch"

button action try this code

```
@IBAction func BtnLocationOnOffSwiftch(_ sender: UIButton) {
    LocaionOnOffSwiftch.isSelected = !LocaionOnOffSwiftch.isSelected
}
```

Comment: You still cannot resize the control correctly for the text fo fit.

Comment: @NEEL PATEL, Thanks for Your answer. But my task is different from Your answer.