# How can I change the size of Xamarin Switch?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The default size of an Xamarin Switch is too big, so I wanted to make it smaller. I tried setting HeightRequest = 20, but it doesn't work on any platform, like UWP, iOS.

Is there a way to change the Switch Size (height)?

Thanks!

James H.

Comment: the underlying UISwitch has a fixed size.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104605/changing-uiswitch-width-and-height

Comment: not recommended, but you can try with `Scale`

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to customize the appearance and behavior of Xamarin.Forms controls.

Try the following steps:

**1.Create a Xamarin.Forms custom CustomSwitch subclassing the Switch control**

```
public class CustomSwitch : Switch
{
    public CustomSwitch()
    {
    }
}
```

**2.Consume the custom control from Xamarin.Forms.**

```
<StackLayout>
    ...
    <local:CustomSwitch IsToggled="true"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**3.Creating the Custom Renderer on iOS.** You could use [CGAffineTransform.MakeScale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/coregraphics.cgaffinetransform.makescale?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14) like @FabriBertani said in the comments.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS

public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    public CustomSwitchRenderer()
    {
    }


    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {

            //Control.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
            Control.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(2f, 2f);
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Customizing an Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry) , [CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(nfloat, nfloat) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/coregraphics.cgaffinetransform.makescale?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14).

Hope it works!